# How to improve concentration when beginning to work on a math problem that seems boring?

Tags: education, advice

I am a college student and my current situation is that I have an extremely hard time getting myself to start doing math. I feel like math is 'boring,' but ONLY until I start actually doing it. Once I get to doing the problems, I start to enjoy it. I read somewhere that all it takes is to force yourself to start on the subject. It supposedly takes 5-20 minutes for the brain to adjust to the current activity, thereby entering a flow state, which is probably the time I start to enjoy it.

Is there someone here who experiences a similar situation, and found a solution that worked for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question! A math book requires a different type of reading than a novel or short story. Every sentence in a math book is full of information and logically linked to the surrounding sentences. You should read the sentences carefully and think about their meaning. As you read, remember that math builds upon itself; earlier methods, that you now find boring, will be useful to you later on. Be sure to read with a pencil and paper: Do calculations, draw sketches, and take notes. (Source: Algebra Structure and Method Book 1 by Brown et al)

Answer (score 2):

Credo ut intelligam.

Have faith in your experience and put in the 5-20 minutes necessary. Then you will see what you have repeatedly found to be true: math is interesting.